# How to Disable / Delete a specific hotkey in Windows 7?

Tags: windows

I'm Romanian and I have the Romanian layout installed so I can use the diacritics (ă,â,ș,ț).

I use the programmers version which requires me to press ALT+SHIFT+A to get Ă and ALT+A to get 'ă' for example.

The problem comes when I try to use the Ș. To type it as a caps, I have to press ALT+SHIFT+S. It's an issue, because this seems to be the shortcut to shutting down your computer.

Being a fast typist, I sometimes use 'Ș' automatically and the PC shuts down. Really annoying and it causes me to lose some unsaved work, lots actually.

Can anyone tell me how to disable this?

Thanks,
Andrei

Comment: It's not a shortcut that is originally included in Windows, that's sure (I just tried it and it did nothing).

Comment: Then, maybe it has something with the language layout?

Comment: P: I would think that some other Software you have installed is responsible for Alt+Shift+S being a shortcut to shut down the computer.

Comment: It's a clean Win7 installation. The only thing I have installed are the basics. Firefix, Winamp, Illustrator, Photoshop.

Comment: Strange. I've tried searching for the hotkey you specified, but came up with nothing. I tried it on my own machine and it did nothing... so why it shuts down the computer for you? I don't know. :(